# Some Emmet codes not working in vscode and atom IDEs

Tags: visual-studio-code, atom-editor, emmet

I checked below Emmet codes not working in vscode.
c{comments here}, doc4, table+, ol+, ul+, select+, bd+, bg+, c:r, c:ra, pos:a

Another thing I have noticed, Some emmit code works differently in different IDEs. For example, I checked below and I got different results in atom and vscode IDEs

.container>h1{course}+p>lorem>a{click here}^p

I couldn't see, 'click here' in atom IDE.

Emmet code bdl works differently in these two IDEs.